# Error installing postgresql through homebrew

Tags: postgresql, installation, homebrew

I was able to install homebrew with no issues, but when I try to install postgresql I get the below error messages:

```
➜  ~ brew install postgresql
Warning: No available formula with the name "postgresql".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

[screen shot of error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wGRW.png)

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you `brew update`?

Answer (score 1):

```
git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master
```

this will switch to master, then run

```
brew doctor
```

this should run without any error.

If there is no error you can install anything with brew install.

ex:

> brew install postgresql

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I fixed by running `brew tap homebrew/core`

After that, postgresql was available to install using:

`brew install postgresql`